# When I press the arrow key forward player goes to the left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made this script

```
public float walkSpeed = 2;
public float runSpeed = 6;
public float turnSmoothTime = 0.2f;
float turnSmoothVelocity;
public float speedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
float speedSmoothVelocity;
float currentSpeed;
Animator animator;

void Start () {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update () {
    Vector2 input = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));
    Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;

    if (inputDir != Vector2.zero) {
        float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2 (inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
    }

    bool running = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift);

    float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;

    currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp (currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, speedSmoothTime);

    transform.Translate (transform.forward * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    float animationSpeedPercent = ((running) ? 1 : .5f) * inputDir.magnitude;

    animator.SetFloat ("speedPercent", animationSpeedPercent, speedSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Now the problem is whenever I click forward with my keys or left right anyway the character is facing 90 degrees away from the way I am actually trying to go. I have tried rotating the character in unity and the 3d modeling program it was made in and still doesnt work. I have been trying to figure this problem out for awhile now please help. Here is an example video : https://streamable.com/u7i0m 
Every time I click a key it goes in the opposite direction its supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Atan2` is backwards. It should be `Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.y, inputDir.x)`.

[image: Geometry]

Depending on how your player is set up, you may also need to offset by + or - 90deg.

```
Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like your model face isn't the transform forwards direction. Either add the offset to your Code or create a Child object to hold the model and rotate that by the offset needed. If you created the model yourself you should fix it their and remember to always create models facing that direction.